# What is difference between Installed audience & User acquisitions on Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

On Google play Console, at the first page of all apps, it shows Installed audience and User acquisition.
I understand Installed audience is the one having my app on their device. But what's user acquisition? usually, User acquisition has high number than Installed audience. But on some apps, Installed audience has high number than User acquisition. I am so confused about this.

Answer (score 8):

Installed audience as google's definition is The number of users who have your app installed on at least 1 device that has been turned on in the last 30 days.

user acquisition as google's definition is The number of users who installed your app and didn’t have it installed on any other devices at the time.

so basically the user acquisition is the total number of installs , and the installed audience is the number of installs that are still active on the device not uninstalled.

when having the time range to a short period (last 30 days ...) the total number of still active installs can be more than the number of new user acquisition in the last 30 days but when setting the time range to lifetime the active installs can't be more than the total acquisition